# Converting RFT legend template into a LYR-file for ArcGIS Desktop 10.x

Tags: arcgis-desktop, convert

I have access to an ArcGIS Server 10.5 Mosaic-service which has a colour-ramp symbology created from an RTF-template. I need to show the legend in ArcGIS but the mosaic is symbolised in the table of contents as a normal RGB raster.

How can I recreate the colour-ramp in ArcGIS from the RFT-file?